# strategy pattern and number of methods in the strategy Interface

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern

When Strategy patten is chosen as a solution, is number of method in the strategy interface should be always one ? i.e execute()

Is strategy pattern chosen wrongly if I need to have more than one method in the interface ?

thanks in advance

Comment: No, you can have more than one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can have more than one method on your strategy interface.  However, in order for your strategy object to actually use the Strategy pattern, at least one of the method implementations should differ between the different strategies.